# Avoid applying CSS style to nested table

Tags: css

I have a table with a nested table, and I want some CSS to be applied only to the outer table. I suspect this can be achieved with the CSS combinator `>`, but I do not succeed.

CSS:

```
.mytable td:nth-of-type(2)  {
    background-color:#0000FF;
}
```

HTML:

```
table>
  <tr>
    <td>Column 1</td>
    <td>Column 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
        <table>
            <tr>
              <td>Column 1</td>
              <td>Column 2</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
   </td>
   <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: you need to consider the fact that there is `tbody` element so `table > tbody > tr > td`

Comment: Ok, this might be helpfull.